# How to store recent search history in to another form?

Tags: vb.net

Still a beginner at coding. My problem is that I want to have a recent search history that will store to a different form. After searching in a textbox, the result form will appear which has a datagrid that contains city ordinances (whatever words/phrases you type in the textbox the result form will appear and all ordinances in the datagrid which has that word the user searched in will appear). What I want to do is that after the user search several times in the database of ordinances I want to store those recent search of ordinances to a separate form? Is it possible? I tried to surf several times in different sites to find a solution but I can't seem to find one. I can find solutions but it uses a web browser navigation, however its not appropriate to my system since its not connected online. Its a City Ordinance Database System (the main function of it is searching so I need the recent file history search) Can someone help me?

```
Private Sub RecentToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RecentToolStripMenuItem.Click
    RecentToolStripMenuItem.MaxItems = 5;
    RecentToolStripMenuItem.Key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Enter"); 
End Sub
```

I tried the above code but it doesn't work.

Comment: Store the recent results in your database. Load the results into a `DataTable`. Bind the datatable to something you want to show the results in, e.g. `DataGridView`, via `DataSource`. Your cde has nothing to do with your question btw.

Comment: im not using binding source for my database. Im using the oledb thing. But I'll try what you just suggested. Thanks

Comment: which database are you using?